# how to show hide a div on dynamic checkbox click event using javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is my html table

```
<table >
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="CU in InboxList">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" onclick="ShowHideDiv(this)" id="checkmailID" ng-model="CU.selected" value="{{CU.InboxMailID}}">
           </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and here is my div which i want to show/hide.

```
<div id="dvPassport">
    <button type="submit" data-placement="top" title="Move to trash"></button>
</div>
```

i have already created a javascript for show/hide the div which is working fine.here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowHideDiv(checkmailID) {
        debugger
        var dvPassport = document.getElementById("dvPassport");
        dvPassport.style.display = checkmailID.checked ? "inline-block" : "none";
    }
</script>
```

there is no problem when i am checking single,mutiple dynamic checkboxes the div is opening.actually i am trying to hide the div when all the checkboxes are unchecked in my html table .the div will show when atleast one checkbox is checked

Comment: If your question is about javascript, you should really make more of an effort to remove all the unnecessary parts of your question. Script tags, html styling, data html attributes, angular references... It just makes it a lot harder to see what you're trying to do.

Comment: actually i am trying to hide the div when all the checkboxes are unchecked in my html table .the div will show when atleast one checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div [hidden] = "value" style="display: inline-block" id="dvPassport">
            <button type="submit" data-placement="top" title="Move to trash"></button>
</div>
```

can you try this please , if you edit the `value` via javascript you can hide an unhide the division

Comment: thanks for replying.but i dont understand what you are saying.

Comment: what i'm trying to say is , as i understand you are trying to find a way to hide and show this division. There is an efficient way to control it ,  if you change the `value` to `false` it will show the div and if you change it to `true` it will hide the division. You can set the conditions of hide and show situations.